# Bootstrap 3 and ScrollTop function: #link conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using BootStrap 3 to build a single page site. To move to the different parts of the page, I find Smooth Scrolling function at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ and it works fine.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Smooth Scrolling detect the links starting with # 
`<a href="#zone">Scroll to Section Zone</a>`

But links starting with # also used in Bootstrap Carousel
 `data-target="#myCarousel"`
So the buttons to move to prev/next slide in the slideshow behave in a wird way.

I have close to no knowledge of Javascript but I realized that the second line of the code was about the links to avoid: so I put "#myCarousel" in that part.
Following you can find the edited second line:

```
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#],"#myCarousel")').click(function() {
```

My solution (very surprising!) works... almost works!
There are only one more issue: the scrolling is NOT anymore smooth.
Clicking on the button the page jump on the target link.

Any idea why is no more smooth?

**Solution Found**

Thanks for all answers.
Before posting this request, I made my searches [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/)

I find a solution: now the second line read 
`$('a[href*=#]').not("[href=#], [href=#myCarousel]").click(function() {`

Answer (score 1):

You destroyed the javascript function because your `:not` selector is written wrong. Therefore the smooth scroll doesn't work anymore. Try doing it this way:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not(#myCarousel)').click(function() {
```

Read more about the `:not CSS selector` [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anot)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for 'destroying' javascritp! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your selector is not working fine.

If you open up your console window and try to write:

`$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#],"#myCarousel")')`

you will see that the result is an error, due to this, the smoothscrolling functionality is not working and the default behaviour of directly showing the links is kicking-in.

[Read more about the jQuery Sizzle engine's .not() selector here.](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Try :

```
$('a[href*=#]').not('[href=#]','#myCarousel').click(function() {
```

This selects the following links:

1. All `a` tags containing # within them.
2. Not having the `href` set directly to `#`
3. Not located within `#myCarousel`